# How to convert datetime dynamically based on culture in c#

Tags: c#

I have created WPF application in C#. In this application I have created one report which is get date from user. For get date , I am using C# datetime control. My datetime control display value as per computer culture. for e.g in my machine when i am selecting date from control, it's display "27-1-2017 12.00.00 AM" when i am test my application in other machine it's display 27/1/2017 12.00.00 AM

So my issue is that I am getting error **"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."** when convert Datetime.

I have tried **DateTime.ParseExact,DateTime.Parse** but still I am not able to succeeded to fix my problem.

```
 DateTime l_dtFrom = Convert.ToDateTime("27-1-2017 12.00.00 AM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
 string l_sFromDate = l_dtFrom.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: Are you sure you *need* to do any conversion at all? You're saying "c# datetime control", it should give you the value as a `DateTime` value, not as a string, are you sure you're accessing the right property of that control?

Comment: Actually I am facing this issue when testing application windows 10 64 bit. and it's working fine in windows 8.1 32 bit machine. As per code date control display date and time based on culture, so in windows 8 machine display date with dash(-) separated and windows 10 display date with slash(/) separated. that's why i am asking

Answer (score 2):

In order to avoid parsing the date time string which depends on current UI thread culture, which in turn might depend on client's regional settings, you should get the `SelectedValue` from your DatePicker control.

If you are using a different control, most certainly, it will deliver the selected value as `DateTime` or even better, as a `DateTime?` (null for no selection). Use this, to work in a culture insensitive way.

Comment: Exactly, I application date control use date time format based on client's regional setting. that's why i need to convert date time in code.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact("27-1-2017 12.00.00 AM", "dd-MM-yyyy hh.mm.ss a", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

With `ParseExact`, you should pass the exact format the string was passed as.

Or try using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` as the format provider in your `Convert.ToDateTime`

**Edit:** Based on the format of string you have provided, I have updated my answer a little. See the format now.